# Attachment related list on custom vf page while creating task

Tags: apex, visualforce, attachment, related-list, tasks

I have created a vf page and have override the New Task button the problem is that on my vf page I am not getting the Attachment Related List as it is coming in standard page.

Is there any tag for that, because even with metadata hit I can update the page Layout not the creation page.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using apex:detail? Did you try this one: <apex:detail relatedList="false"/>
  <apex:relatedList list="Attachments"  subject="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}" />

Comment: @AyubAnsari I want the related list on the task creation page.  <apex:relatedList list="Attachments"> will not work in this case.